# server response to options was not found

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm working on a REST service in web API (asp net 5) that the website can successfully send a request to it, but when the service sends the request options to the website, the reply says `HTTP 1/1 404 Not Found`.

[Fiddler Screenshot of the "Options" request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXOfW.png)

---

The service's controllers are configured by

```
public class Startup {
        public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();
    }
}
```

---

A function the website has to access is:

```
[Route("/operator")] // localhost:5000/operator
public class OperatorController : Controller
[EnableCors(origins:'*', headers>'*', methods:'*');
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return new HttpOkObject("Hello, select your operation");
}
```

---

The website accessing this function (sending the route to the class calls Index) is implemented using ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var options = {};
        options.url = "http://localhost:5000/installments";
        options.type = "GET";
        options.contentType = "application/jsonp";
        // options.dataType="jsonp";

        options.success = function (results) {
             alert(results.join);
        };

        options.error = function(evt){
            alert(evt.status + " - " + evt.statusText)
        };

        $.ajax(options);
    });
 </script>
```

---

[EDIT]
adding the line

```
<pre><code>app.Use(async (context, next) => {  context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); await next(); });</code></pre>
```

Before
    `app.UseMvc();`

Adds the needed header, but I get the error
    `“Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404”`

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the route and method to use to your function inside the controller. You can define a default mapping inside the Startup class.

```
HttpConfiguration configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Or you can explicitly declare the route in the function with the following tag.

```
[EnableCors(origins:'*', headers>'*', methods:'*');
[HttpGet]
[Route("printheads/")]
public IActionResilt Index()
{
    return new HttpOkObject("Hello, select your operation");
}
```

Comment: But I think that the method it's mandatory. Check that I have [HttpGet] in order to config which HTTP method will use that route. I Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

solved it by doing the following:

in Setup.cs, inside

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
```

add the following lines:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => { context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); await next(); });
app.Use(async (context, next) => { context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*"); await next(); });
app.Use(async (context, next) => { context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600"); await next(); });
app.Use(async (context, next) => { context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"); await next(); });
```